# Microphone replacement

Tags: amplifier, transformer, microphone

I have a device containing an active mic, an amplifier, and an AD converter. I would like to swap the microphone with another completely different mic. I have no tech specs on the microphone that I'm replacing. Would it be a good idea measure the voltage output of the original mic in response to some sine waves at various frequencies and then wind a simple toroidal transformer to get the output of the new mic to look similar?

...or would this be totally dumb?

Comment: What sort of microphone is it?  Failing that, what known microphones in catalogs match the general visual appearance?  And as importantly, what does the device do?  If there is a calibration of some sort which could be thrown off, you may not be able to equalize it in one step across all frequencies, but in most applications there would not be a precise calibration to worry about in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who designs pro-audio equipment for a living I can confidently say that this would be totally dumb.  Here's why:

- No tech specs on the old mic.
- No tech specs on the new mic.
- No tech specs on the device that you want to swap mics on.
- No mention on what performance levels you want.
- Hand winding transformers for audio is difficult at best.
- Measuring the voltage at various frequencies is only part of the equation.

Given your interest in VST Plugins, I am going to assume that you want pro-audio level of performance.  And based on your previous questions, I am going to assume that you are fairly new at electrical engineering (that's not a criticism, as we all have to start somewhere and that is after all why you are here).

Mic pre-amp circuits are difficult, even for seasoned EE's.  Doing a pro-audio level circuit (or even a consumer grade circuit) is difficult without good specs and the test equipment to verify that it is working correctly.

Using a transformer for this is not at all advised.  Yes, that is how they used to do it "back in the day" but designing and building a transformer that works well across the entire audio frequency band is difficult.  I know many really good pro-audio EE's, but maybe only one of them could design this transformer.  You could buy a reasonable Jensen transformer that is designed for this, but it will cost you a minimum of US$100/each and probably won't have the required turns ratio.

If you want to do this as a learning process, and I highly approve of doing things to just learn stuff, this is still the wrong thing to do.  Modifying gear like this, when you don't have a complete understanding of what is going on (no specs, etc.) is just super frustrating.  You would be much better off just buying the exact thing that you need, and picking a different audio project to work on.  Otherwise you run the risk of damaging an otherwise good piece of gear, not getting the device you really want, and getting frustrated and abandoning your EE ambitions.  And that's never a good thing.

Comment: The assumption that he's pro-level based on the mention of VST is a little naive... every guy with a pirated copy of Reason or any of the other audio recording software has at least a few thousand pirated VSTs as well.  Not saying THIS guy is pirating anything, but I'm also willing to bet he is just trying to get something to work, rather than a pro-level solution. I'd guess he was not looking for pro quality since most people serious about their craft will know what equipment they're using at a minimum.  Very good answer, though, and +1 from me.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith Well, his blog site talks about making your own VST plugins.  Obviously a hobby and not "pro", but is a very long way from being a VST pirate.  Even so, my assumption may be incorrect-- but that is exactly why I said it was an assumption!  :)

Comment: Sometimes formulating a question makes you realise just how unfeasible an idea is when there are so many unknowns. Thanks for solidly confirming my doubts. +1. However, I fail to see what piracy has to do with this. LOL

Comment: it has nothing to do with piracy; I was just saying that almost every mention of VST I've run across involves garage band types with hundreds if not thousands of pirated VST plugins. :-)